# Como colocar default em parâmetros quando se especifica o tipo do objeto?

Tags: python, funções

Quando defino funções, costumo usar o recurso de especificar o tipo de objeto que pode ser utilizado como argumento e qual objeto a função deve retornar. Veja exemplo a seguir:

```
def count_elements(lista_a: list, lista_b:list)->int:
    result = len(lista_a)+len(lista_b)
    return result

count_elements([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

Output:

```
6
```

Ocorre que quando tento estabelecer valores padrões, o python retorna a mensagem `invalid syntax`. Eu tentei dessa forma, sem sucesso:

```
def count_elements(lista_a: list, lista_b = [1,2,3]:list)->int:
    result = len(lista_a)+len(lista_b)
    return result
```

É possível estabelecer argumento *default* e especificar o tipo de objeto ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ordem da annotation (a marcação de tipo) e os valores default é ao contrário do que você está tentando fazer: primeiro o nome do parâmetro, o sinal de `:`, a anotação, e aí sim o sinal de `=` seguido do valor padrão:

```
def count_elements(lista_a: list, lista_b: list = [1,2,3])->int:
    result = len(lista_a)+len(lista_b)
    return result
```

---

Esse código tem um outro erro, dessa vez bem mais sútil, então aproveito para comentar: **nunca** se deve colocar uma lista, ou outro objeto mutável como valor padrão de um parâmetro.

Isso por que os objetos usados como valor padrão são criados uma única vez, quando a função é criada, e re-utilizados em todas as chamadas aquela função  - então se a função altera a lista, numa segunda chamada à função, a lista aparece alterada:

```
# exemplo do problema no terminal interativo: 

>>> def aumenta_lista(lista=[]):
...     lista.append(len(lista))
...     return lista
... 
>>> aumenta_lista()
[0]
>>> aumenta_lista()
[0, 1]
>>> aumenta_lista()
[0, 1, 2]
```

O correto nesses casos é usar `None` para dispensar quem chama a função de enviar o parâmetro, e criar a lista dentro da função, usando um `if`:

```
def count_elements(lista_a: list, lista_b: list=None)->int:
    if lista_b is None:
        lista_b = [1, 2, 3]
    result = len(lista_a)+len(lista_b)
    return result
```

Isso garante que a  `lista_b` vai ser criada dentro da função cada vez que for chamada. **MAS** veja, que agora o parâmetro padrão é um `None`, que não é uma lista!  Então, para a tipagem ficar correta nesses casos, e ser aprovada por ferramentas de verificação, é necessário dizer que esse parâmetro tem que poder ser OU uma lista OU um None.

O módulo `typing` da biblioteca padrão tem a classe `Optional` para esses casos - o correto então é assim:

```
import typing as T


def count_elements(lista_a: list, lista_b: T.Optional[list] = None)->int:
    if lista_b is None:
        lista_b = [1, 2, 3]
    result = len(lista_a)+len(lista_b)
    return result
```

(O módulo Typing tem várias classes que são feitas para serem usadas com a sintaxe de `[ ]`, para detalhar mais coisas sobre a anotação de tipo - vale a pena depois ver a documentação de como ele é usado)